# Formulário redirecionando

Tags: php, javascript

Olá!

Então, eu criei um formulário em PHP e JS, porém ele redireciona pra uma página em branco falando apenas que ela foi enviada. O problema é que deveria aparecer na mesma página, sem ser redirecionado.

Esse é o HTML

```html
<section id="formFolder">
            <img class="imgWire" src="assets/img/main/Wire-PNG.png" alt="">
            <img class="imgWire2" src="assets/img/main/Wire-PNG.png" alt="">
            <div class="container">
                <form id="contact-form-folder" method="post" action="mail/contact-folder.php" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 divFormBlog">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4 class="text-center folderText">FOLDER DIGITAL</h4>
                                <h5 class="text-center recebaText">Receba nosso folder no seu e-mail:</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 inputDiv1">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 inputDiv2">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 divLink">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send btnEnviarForm btnEnviar" value="Enviar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Esse é o php:

```html
<?php


// contact-folder.PHP - CONTACT FORM SEND FILE - THINKBEYOND [ DEV TEAM ]
// www.tbdesenvolvimento.com.br - #OFuturoÉOnline


// configure
$from = 'Formulario de Contato <formularios@tbdesenvolvimento.com.br>';
$sendTo = 'Contato <contato@jfsecurity.com.br>';
// $sendTo = 'Contato <marketing@musca.io>';
$subject = 'Folder Digital - Nova solicitação';
$fields = array('nome' => 'Nome ',  'email' => 'Email ', 'phone' => 'Telefone '); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Folder digital enviado!' ;
$errorMessage = 'Ops, ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente.';

// let's do the sending
try
{
    $emailText = "Olá JF Security, você recebeu uma solicitação do seu folder digital através do formulário do seu site.\n\nLembre-se de responder a essa mensagem através do email fornecido abaixo pelo visitante do seu site!\n\n\nAqui estão as informações:\n\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }

    }

require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From      = 'formularios@tbdesenvolvimento.com.br';
$mail->FromName  = 'Formulário de Contato';
$mail->Subject   = 'Formulário - Contato';
$mail->Body      = $emailText;
$mail->AddAddress( 'contato@jfsecurity.com.br' );
$retorno = $mail->Send();

$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$mail2->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail2->From      = 'contato@jfsecurity.com.br';
$mail2->FromName  = 'Contato - JF Security';
$mail2->Subject   = 'Folder Digital - JF Security';
$mail2->IsHtml(true);
$mail2->Body      = "Olá ". $_POST["nome"] . ", obrigado por entrar em contato conosco!<br> A apresentação está anexada nesse email conforme solicitado. Em caso de dúvida entre em contato <a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5511988003086&text=Ol%C3%A1!%20Eu%20solicitei%20a%20apresentação%20da%20da%20Musca%20e%20gostaria%20de%20algumas%20informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es!'>(11) 9 8800-3086</a>";
$mail2->AddAddress($_POST["email"]);
$mail2->AddAttachment("../PDF/folder-digital.pdf");
$retorno2 = $mail2->Send();
exit(json_encode($okMessage));
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
       'From: ' . $from,
       'Reply-To: ' . $from,
       'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

E esse é o JS:

```js
/*FORMULÁRIO FOLDER*/
$('#contact-form-folder').validator();

    $('#contact-form-folder').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "../mail/contact-folder.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "to": $(this)[0][1].value,
                    "attachmentKey": "..PDF/novo-catalogo-de-produtos-e-servicos-jf-security.pdf",
                    "department": "marketing",
                    "data": {
                        "email": $(this)[0][1].value,
                        "nome": $(this)[0][0].value
                    }
                }),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    if (data.success) {
                        messageAlert = 'alert-success';
                        messageText = 'Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!';
                    }else{
                        messageAlert = 'alert-danger';
                        messageText = 'Sua mensagem não pode ser enviada...';
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
/*FIM FORMULÁRIO FOLDER*/
```

Comment: Qual é esse plugin `.validator()`?

Comment: Então você quer dispara o ajax, mas não sair da tela é isso ?

Comment: O "validator" é um plugin a parte... Já fiz os testes e o problema não é nele.

Comment: Eu quero que apenas apareça uma mensagem "Sua mensagem foi enviada!" logo abaixo do botão "Enviar"

Answer (score 0):

Ele ta movendo por que você declarou um action se tiver usando php na mesma página só tirar o action se não na outra página se tudo ocorrer bem coloca um `header('location: destino.php');`

OBS: Troque destino pra onde ele tem que ir...